# Characterization of simply connected bounded regions in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I do not know if the following is true:
A bounded region $U$ is simply connected if and only if for any holomorphic function $f$ on $U$ and any closed curve $\gamma\subseteq{U}$ we have $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$$. The "only if" part follows from the homotopy of curves theorem, but I don't know how to begin with the "if" part, intuitively I think it is because the integral condition implies that $U$ has no "holes", and this implies $U$ is biholomorphic to an open ball.

Or to prove that the interior of a closed curve is simply connected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It $U$ is not simply connected, then there exists a simple closed curve $\gamma:S^1\to U$, such that $U$ does not contain the bounded connected component $C$ of $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\gamma(S^1)}$. Choose $z_0\in C\setminus U$ and let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-z_0}$.  Then $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ but $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=2\pi i$.

Comment: I thought this too, but the thing is, how to prove such curve exists, this could be done proving that the interior of a closed curve is simply connected.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: It follows from Jordan curve theorem, or more accurately, Jordan–Schönflies theorem.

Comment: why this is so?

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: There may not be complex analysis involved in the proof of Jordan–Schönflies theorem, but it has a strengthened version in complex analysis, [Carathéodory's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)), which also implies your result.